# GATE 2024 CSE SET-1, Assume that the input to the program from the command line is 1234 followed by a newline character? which option is correct

Tags: c

[image]

.

my question is that can we use command line arguments without the use of main function arguments if yes then how in this program we can use them to get answer?

according to me the main function should be like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  //program block
}
```

I chosed the option B in the exam.

Thank you!

---

After Execution i got:

[image]

Comment: I think the question itself is badly worded. I would assume that the author meant that the input is written in the command-line environment (the *console* or *terminal*), like normal input, and not as command-line arguments. Otherwise the program would make no sense.

Comment: Also please note that [the `getchar` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`** value, which is important when you need to check the result for the integer value `EOF`. Which the code really should do. As it is now, an `EOF` would lead to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

> my question is that can we use command line arguments without the use of main function arguments

Well yeah on some systems that's possible by using OS-specific API functions.

But that's not what the question refers to at all - "command line" in this context is probably just referring to `stdin` from the shell/console/terminal. That is - the stuff obtained by calling `getchar`. So I think you have misunderstood what the question meant, it is oddly phrased.

- Other than that, it doesn't look like the program will compile at all since ´ is not a valid source code symbol in C. This would be why we write source code in modern programming IDEs, not in MS Word nor on old typewriters from the 1980s...
- Other than that, `getchar()` returns an `int` and a classic beginner mistake is to use `char` instead, since logically `getchar` ought to get a char, but the C standard lib was never very logical nor well-designed. In this case it doesn't matter, but maybe the teacher doesn't know how `getchar()` works.
- Other than that, recursion is generally bad practice for most purposes and ideally shouldn't be taught to beginners at all since it's such useless knowledge with very few real world use-case scenarios.
- Other than that, we don't invent our own sloppy, private coding standards when teaching C, so gunk like `putchar(a);}` will never pass peer code review. Nobody writes C like that. Except your teacher, apparently...

Overall, this is a bad C class. Feel free to forward my thoughts to your teacher.

That being said, simply type down the program and check for yourself? It is not option B. Or alternatively try to illustrate the recursion on pen and paper (or a typewriter!) and see what you come up with.

Comment: I got the reverse char string after executing and thank you for the great insights!

by the way this is not a semester exam question this question was asked in a competitive exam for computer engineers this year and the paper was set by the IISC Bangalore that is ranked among the top research university in the world.

Comment: @rahul Such a ranking might or might not mean anything. I think, Harvard is also rather good, but their CS50 course doesn't make me cheer. Mixing `stdin` with command line arguments is a poor choice of wording. Instructions should be precise and these are not. Also the formatting of the code is terrible and should not be presented to anyone learning C.

Comment: This poor wording got me to choose wrong option B.

Happy Coding!